# Radio Toggle Button Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio type Toggle buttons. There are Three buttons and option to select only one button at a time. But the problem is buttons always remain selected(I know radio button don't have option to unchecked ). There is no Option to Unchecked all.

I would like to Do something like this:

If any selected button clicked again it will Unchecked . But if not clicked on the selected button it will work same what it is in current.

Is this possible to make? Sorry for bad English

Here is Demo link: [**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/eQ744/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin:0px auto; margin-top:100px; width:960px;">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
    </a>


    <a href="#">
        <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
    </a>


    <a href="#">
        <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0px;
}

body {
 background: #fafafa;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.813em;
 color:#333333;


}

a {color:#737373;text-decoration:none;
}

a:link { text-decoration: none;outline: none;
}

a:visited {text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {color:#454545;
}

a:active {text-decoration: none;
}

ul {list-style: none; text-decoration: none;
}

ol {list-style-position: inside; color:#333333;padding:12px 10px 25px 15px;font-size: 1.07em;}
ol, li {padding-bottom:8px;}

img {}
em {color: #737373; font-weight:300;}

h1 {color: #737378; margin:20px 5px 20px 0px; font-size:2.4em; text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:100; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff; }
h2 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}
h3 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}
h4 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 20px 0px; font-size:1.2em; width:98%; border-bottom:1px solid #eee;padding-bottom:10px;}
h5 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}
h6 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}

p { color:#333; font-size:1.154em; margin:5px 10px 10px 0px; padding-bottom:10px;line-height:140%;}

hr { border: 0; clear: both; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: #bbbbbb; height: 1px; margin: 5px 0px;
}

select {
 color: #454545;
}

.toggleButtonRadio , .toggleButton {
 background: #e1e1e1; 
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: .769em;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #454545;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(64, 64, 64, .5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(64, 64, 64, .5);
}

.toggleButtonRadio:hover, .toggleButton:hover{
 background:#d4d4d4;
}

.toggleButtonRadio.active , .toggleButton.active{
background:#90bf00;
color:#fff;
}

.active:hover{
background:#7ca600;
}
```

**js**

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').removeClass("active");      
    $(this).toggleClass("active");


    });
```

Comment: Why are you not using actual HTML radio buttons (i.e., `<input type="radio">`)?  This is the default behavior for them.

Comment: Add a fourth radio button and call it "none of the above".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').not(this).removeClass("active");      
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

This should do what you want, since it removes the `active` class on all siblings (hence the `.not(this)`. Then the clicked button's `active` class is toggled on or of.

Edit: changed `$(this)` to `this`, its simpler.

Comment: Thank you @Palatiner :) that was simple. I have a lack of knowledge on JQuery and Js.

Thank for the Share.

Comment: You're welcome! When I found out about ``.not( ... )``, I thought: "I would have needed this a long time ago!"

Answer (score 3):

I have solved your problem with a simple IF ELSE statment:

**JQuery**

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $('.toggleButtonRadio').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the same solution and deleted it - Jamie Read was first with the correct solution. :-)