# Radio toggle button upgrading functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem: I want a three way toggle on my radio buttons.

Example: all gray to start, first click on button 1 changes it to green, second click on the SAME button 1, changes it to peach, any following click will cycle between these two states. A click on any other button will reset this back to the original state.

I have Three Radio type Toggle button. Only one button can select a time like the radio.
Also If any selected button is clicked again it will unchecked. I am trying to add something more in this.

I am wanting something like this:

Initially the buttons are gray.

If any button is  clicked, the button  turns into gray from green. Again clicking that selected button turns back to gray.

**But** what I am wanting initially all buttons will stay Gray but If I click any one first It will turn into green color and again click the same button will give another color (can be any color). again clicking same button will back to green and will go on.. But IF I clicked to another button previous button will Change to Gray and Current button can Do the same .

This was requirement for one of my College project. But Finding no way for making like this.

Should be Made with keeping current functionalities. Hope I am clear about the requirements. If this can be done it would be Great for me.

here is the link for current Example: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/eQ744/7/)

**HTML:**

```
<div style="margin:0px auto; margin-top:100px; width:960px;">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
    </a>


    <a href="#">
        <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
    </a>


    <a href="#">
        <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0px;
}

body {
 background: #fafafa;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.813em;
 color:#333333;


}

a {color:#737373;text-decoration:none;
}

a:link { text-decoration: none;outline: none;
}

a:visited {text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {color:#454545;
}

a:active {text-decoration: none;
}

ul {list-style: none; text-decoration: none;
}

ol {list-style-position: inside; color:#333333;padding:12px 10px 25px 15px;font-size: 1.07em;}
ol, li {padding-bottom:8px;}

img {}
em {color: #737373; font-weight:300;}

h1 {color: #737378; margin:20px 5px 20px 0px; font-size:2.4em; text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:100; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff; }
h2 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}
h3 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}
h4 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 20px 0px; font-size:1.2em; width:98%; border-bottom:1px solid #eee;padding-bottom:10px;}
h5 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}
h6 {color: #454545; margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;}

p { color:#333; font-size:1.154em; margin:5px 10px 10px 0px; padding-bottom:10px;line-height:140%;}

hr { border: 0; clear: both; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: #bbbbbb; height: 1px; margin: 5px 0px;
}

select {
 color: #454545;
}

.toggleButtonRadio , .toggleButton {
 background: #e1e1e1; 
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: .769em;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #454545;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(64, 64, 64, .5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(64, 64, 64, .5);
}

.toggleButtonRadio:hover, .toggleButton:hover{
 background:#d4d4d4;
}

.toggleButtonRadio.active , .toggleButton.active{
background:#90bf00;
color:#fff;
}

.active:hover{
background:#7ca600;
}

.active2{

    background:#fcc79a;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').not(this).removeClass("active");        
    $(this).toggleClass("active");


    });
```

Comment: Initially: gray -> when clicked: turns gray from  green -> clicked again: turns back to gray **what do you want?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio Toggle Button Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846083/radio-toggle-button-issue)

Comment: You continue to add the same question even though you have an answer, please stop spamming the site.

Comment: No it's not Duplicate and not Trying to Spam. Please do not Misunderstood. In title I mentioned Upgrade of Radio button functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve?

You want the SECOND click on the button to activate a SECOND active class?

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("normal")) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).removeClass("normal");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).addClass("active2");
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("active2")) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).removeClass("active2");
    }

    $('.toggleButtonRadio').not(this).removeClass("active");
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').not(this).removeClass("active2");
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').not(this).addClass("normal");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/HPC5y/

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Actually not Like this.

Almost perfect just noticed clicking same button again and again bring back the Gray color back but it shouldn't be ... It will always remain between that two color until I click another buton

Comment: After 3 clicks still the Gray color appear !! Yes you can modify CSS if you need

Comment: Thanks Man for helping. Still an issue. Regardless I am experimenting with your suggetions

Comment: Click once, green, twice peach, three times again Green ,4th again Peach and will continue same Until Next button click ...

Almost just need a loop on Green and peach until next button clicked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40837/discussion-between-mutmatt-and-s-raihan)